# Can't customize action mode context popup background and shape with material components

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

guys.

I'm not a pro in developing android applications, and faced with issue related to the CAB popup background that raised with migration to android material components.

I have applied custom colors to my new Material theme and overall it has applied well, but in Action Mode, when "More" button is clicked, then background and style of popup menu has styles of default menu and I can't change it in any way.

[image: toolbar]

[image: toolbar-popup]

I have already tried all possible solutions from stackoverflow, but nothing helps or gives just half effect that makes it look very ugly

Here is the activity description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myestimates.activity.project.bindmaterial.SelectMaterialsToBindActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Myestimates.Material.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/Myestimates.Material.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Myestimates.Material.TabLayout"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here is the theme/styles I have:

```
<style name="Myestimates.Material" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primary_color_light</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/primary_color_on</item>

        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondary_color</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/secondary_color_light</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/secondary_color_on</item>

        <item name="colorSurface">@color/surface_color</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/surface_color_on</item>

        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_color</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/background_color_on</item>

        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/TextInputField</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/background_color</item>

        <item name="checkboxStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Myestimates.Material.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="Myestimates.Material.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

    <style name="Myestimates.Material.TabLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored" />
```

What I want to achieve right now, is to have black background without additional vertical spaces and corner rounding on CAB popup.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same probelm, just with black over black

Comment: Hi, Have you found a solution?